# Debugging Revit plug in through the Visual Studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio, revit-api

I want to step through and debug Revit Add-ins.  When I hit F5 to run Revit through Visual Studio, I get the Revit "splash" screen, then Revit almost immediately closes.  I've followed the instructions here...

http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=20132893

I added the correct lines to *.csproj...

`<StartAction>Program</StartAction>
<StartProgram>C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2016\Revit.exe</StartProgram>`

and also modified the Debug settings...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Enable managed mode debugging](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/use-managed-compatibility-mode-or-enable-native-code-debugging/m-p/6868592).